# How to single input field to appear as OTP design?

Tags: html, css

facing issue in design OTP screen in single input using html and css.[image: Please check this image for more info]

want to show 6 character like otp design with spacing.
could someone please help me out of this using html css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, You can do like this.

Hope it will help you.

```css
.otp-input-wrapper {
  width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.otp-input-wrapper input {
padding: 0;
width: 264px;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #3e3e3e;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
margin-left: 2px;
letter-spacing: 30px;
font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
.otp-input-wrapper input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.otp-input-wrapper svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="otp-input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" maxlength="6" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="off">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="240" y2="0" stroke="#3e3e3e" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,22" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the input to be aligned center and responsive.For that I gave svg width as 100%. Now am facing letter spacing issues with different screen sizes.Can any one help me on this?